# Conversion of a byte array subset to a primitive in Java

Tags: java

This is my very first post on Stackoverflow so please go easy on me :)

I am looking for a more processor-efficient way of performing byte array conversions to primitive types in Java.

The byte array contains a data stream which is made up of many different primitive types. For the purpose of this question, let's just assume that is contains INT's and for brevity, ignore endian.

In C, I can extract an INT very efficiently via pointers: IE

```
int *value;
unsigned char data[MAX_LEN_DATA];

value = (int *)&data[10];
```

To perform the same in Java, is it true that I need to compute the value. IE, something like:

```
int value;
byte[] data;

value = (data[10]<<24) | (data[11]<<16) | (data[12]<<8) | data[13];
```

Is there a more processor-efficient method such as the C example or does Java utilise CPU barrel shifting (Intel & AMD in my case) in which case, my question becomes superfluous ... but maybe useful for others :)

Comment: In general, the answer is *yes*. You have to ready byte input stream byte by byte and convert yourself to required data.

Comment: In general yes, this how you need to do this. You could wrap it in a `ByteBuffer` and use that for reading ints, but that just shifts the problem.

Comment: The first question a java person asks: is it really a problem for you? Meaning: have you measured your program execution, and is it *really* on a level that creates a problem?! So, efficiency shouldnt be neglected. But in java, you are very careful about such kind of "source code optimisations". You rather prefer to write simple code, so that the JIT can turn it into highly optimised machine code for you.

Comment: A JVM could recognize the pattern and optimize it for you - you can't control these things in the Java language itself. But as @MarkRotteveel said, you could look into `ByteBuffer` and friend APIs.

Comment: You will have to use [Java Native Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) to use pointers. Otherwise you do the bit shifting.

Comment: Another important thing to be aware off, is that a Java Virtual Machine may optimize things in ways you can't easily guess at. For example, it is entirely possible that `ByteBuffer.getInt()` is runtime replaced with an optimized native variant, while that is not apparent from the source itself. The same might be done for  the naive bit shifting variant. In general in Java, don't try to do smart things for sake of performance, unless you have proven (eg using JMH or profiling) that it is a bottleneck and that your optimization is actually beneficial.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your input - very much appreciated!